# divergence/convergence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5k+2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5k+2}$$

Can I say that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5k+2}=\sum_{k=1}\frac{1}{5k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2}$$

and we know that $\\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$ diverges so the expression diverges too?

Or should I use the integral test $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5k+2}=\frac{ln|5k+2|}{5}$$ from 1 to $\infty$=  $\infty$

Comment: $\frac{1}{5k+2}\neq\frac{1}{5k}+\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2}\neq\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: The sum obviously diverges. You can use a variant of the proof that the sum of 1/k diverges.

Comment: You are on the right track: Just lower bound the series with suitable scaled harmonic series: Hint: Consider $\frac{1}{5k+2}>\frac{1}{5k+2k}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $n=1,2,\cdots$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{5k+2}>\frac{1}5\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+1}>\frac{1}{10} \:\ln n
$$ and conclude to the **divergence** of the initial series.

Comment: Nice and clean answer... To address the initial question, though: *the proof suggested by the OP is wrong*, since the very first equality does not hold: $\frac{1}{5k+2}\neq \frac{1}{5k}+\frac{1}{2}$. (The second is also wrong, for that matter, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2} = \infty \neq\frac{1}{2}$.)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10k}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5k+2}$$
which is true because 
$$ \frac{1}{10k}<\frac{1}{5k+2}\:\:\forall k\in \mathbb{N}.$$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{10k}=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$$
which implies that it diverges. So, because 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{5k+2}$$
is greater term by term than a series which diverges, it too diverges.